# How do I pass an array to ng-options in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

My array is something like this:

```
$scope.states = [{                  
    "AB" : "Abia",
    "AJ" : "Abuja",                
    "AN" : "Anambra"}];
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<select ng-options="state for state in states">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

How do I properly pass it over?

Comment: Your Plunkr demo is very complicated and not representative of the question

Comment: @Vlad274 , just looking at the snippet of code is what i need to know m the plunker is pretty irrelevant

Comment: @AnthonyAkpan, what is `state.[0]`? this is not a valid syntax. Also, `ng-options` requires `ng-model`

Comment: @NewDev , just me trying to figure it out

Comment: @AnthonyAkpan, also your `states` array has only a single element. Is this intentional? And if you intend to use an object, then the syntax is `ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in states"` (or something like that)

Comment: @NewDev , i was wondering about that i originally converted the array of states from some php code that is structured using key , pair values. I didnt really want to rewrite it as purely an array if i didnt have to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `states` is an array with a single element - an object with states as key/value pairs. You can still use an object with `ng-options` - not sure though why an array is needed - so long as you refer to the source object with `"... in states[0]"`.

`ng-options` also requires an `ng-model`.

```
<select ng-model="selectedState"
        ng-options="key as state for (key, state) in states[0]">
</select>
```

The above would set `selectedState` to `key` (i.e. the abbreviation). You can set it to `state` as well).

Of course, if you don't need `states` to be an array of a single element and just set it to the element itself, then you could refer to it as `"...(key, state) in states"` rather than `... in states[0]"`.

Answer (score 1):

**JS:**

```
$scope.states = {
        "AB" : "Abia",
        "AJ" : "Abuja",
        "AN" : "Anambra"};
```

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in states"></select>
```